# why must one use __iter__() method in classes?

Tags: python

What exactly is the role of **iter**? Consider the following code block:

```
class Reverse:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.index = len(data)
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def next(self):
        if self.index == 0:
            raise StopIteration
        self.index = self.index - 1
        return self.data[self.index]
```

omitting **iter**(self) and rewritting:

```
class Reverse2:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.index = len(data)
    def next(self):
        if self.index == 0:
            raise StopIteration
        self.index = self.index - 1
        return self.data[self.index]
```

Then:

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = Reverse(x)
z = Reverse2(x)
y.next()
>>> 3
y.next()
>>> 2
y.next()
>>> 1
z.next()
>>> 3
z.next()
>>> 2
z.next()
>>> 1
```

The classes behave the same way regardless of whether I include **iter**() or not, so why should i include it in the first place? I'm sorry if my question isn't clear--I simply don't know how to state it in a more clear way...

Answer (score 1):

The `__iter__` method is always called, when an iterator is needed, e.g. by explicitly calling `iter` or in `for`-loops or when creating lists `list(xy)`.

So you cannot use your second class `Reverse2` in all these contexts.

```
>>> list(Reverse("abc"))
['c', 'b', 'a']
>>> list(Reverse2("abc"))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: iteration over non-sequence
```

To answer the question in the comment: the `__iter__`-method must return any iterator or instance with a `__next__`-method. Only if your class is a iterator by itself, it should return `self`. An example of returning a generator as iterator:

```
class Reverse3:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
    def __iter__(self):
        # returns an generator as iterator
        for idx in range(len(self.data)-1, -1, -1):
            yield self.data[idx]
```

Comment: ok I understand why __iter__ must be included now, but why should I make that method return 'self'?

Comment: @KevinMoon: see my answer, but you should also edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

The __iter__ return the [iterator object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) which allows to convert the object to a container which can be iterated via `for .. in ..`.

The iterator object is any object which define __next__ method which returns the next item if exists or raise `StopIteration` otherwise.

While __iter__ can return any such iterator object, It can return itself if it implement __next__ method.

For example:

```
class Reverse:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.index = len(data)
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        if self.index == 0:
            raise StopIteration
        self.index = self.index - 1
        return self.data[self.index]
```

Now you can use in for loops:

```
for xx in Reverse(x):
    print xx
```

Comment: ok I understand why __iter__ must be included now, but why should I make that method return 'self'?